# Google OAuth 2.0 TokenResponseException when user deny on consent screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

I'm implementing Google OAuth 2.0 authentication to fetch user specific data as mentioned here [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) with the help of Google API Client Libraries for .NET. Everything works fine.

However, when user click on Deny on Google consent screen, given example fails and it throw an exception

> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"access_denied", Description:"", Uri:""

Answer (score 0):

please add this method in

> AuthCallbackController.cs

```
>  protected override ActionResult OnTokenError(TokenErrorResponse
> errorResponse)
>     {
>         return RedirectToAction("ConnectGoogleAsync", "Integration", new { errorResp = errorResponse });
>     }
```